# Converting factor in different formats to date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe `data2` with a variable `x.date` in different formats:

```
[1] "42250"      "14/03/2015" "14/03/2015" "42311"     
   [5] "42158"      "42158"      "19/03/2015" "19/03/2015"
   [9] "19/03/2015" "19/03/2015" "19/03/2015" "18/03/2015"
```

I need to convert it to dd/mm/yyyy format, if I try the following:

```
as.Date(data2$x.date format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

I receive NAs:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [20] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What could be a solution to this?

Comment: the `format=` you specify needs to match your data, or at least some of it, to work. `14/03/2015` and the other similar examples are `"%d/%m/%Y"` not `"%m/%d/%Y"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are just these two types of formats, you can try

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = format(coalesce(dmy(x.date),
                                as_date(as.integer(x.date), origin = "1900-01-01")),
                       "%d-%m-%Y")) %>% 
  suppressWarnings()
```

which returns

```
   col1     x.date       date
1     a      42250 05-09-2015
2     b 14/03/2015 14-03-2015
3     c 14/03/2015 14-03-2015
4     d      42311 05-11-2015
5     e      42158 05-06-2015
6     f      42158 05-06-2015
7     g 19/03/2015 19-03-2015
8     h 19/03/2015 19-03-2015
9     i 19/03/2015 19-03-2015
10    j 19/03/2015 19-03-2015
11    k 19/03/2015 19-03-2015
12    l 18/03/2015 18-03-2015
```

Note: I'm not sure which date is the correct origin for your 42250 formats. This could be 1899/12/31 or 1899/12/30 or 1900/01/01.

### Data

```
structure(list(col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l"), x.date = c("42250", "14/03/2015", "14/03/2015", 
"42311", "42158", "42158", "19/03/2015", "19/03/2015", "19/03/2015", 
"19/03/2015", "19/03/2015", "18/03/2015")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the data in Date class then using `format` you can get it in any format.

Here is a base R approach -

```
#Create a column to save dates
data2$dates <- as.Date(NA)
#Find out dates which has only numbers
inds <- grepl('^\\d+$', data2$x.date)
#Change excel date to R date
data2$dates[inds] <- as.Date(as.numeric(data2$x.date[inds]), origin = "1899-12-30")
#For remaining ones use dmy format to change the dates
data2$dates[!inds] <- as.Date(data2$x.date[!inds], '%d/%m/%Y')
#change the format of dates. 
data2$dates <- format(data2$dates, '%d/%m/%Y')

#[1] "03/09/2015" "14/03/2015" "14/03/2015" "03/11/2015" "03/06/2015" "03/06/2015"
#[7] "19/03/2015" "19/03/2015" "19/03/2015" "19/03/2015" "19/03/2015" "18/03/2015"
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to do this `data2$dates[inds]` and `data2$dates[!inds]` in one assignment? I couldn't figure it out...

Comment: `dplyr::if_else(inds, as.Date(as.numeric(data2$x.date), origin = "1899-12-30"), as.Date(data2$x.date, '%d/%m/%Y'))` works but returns a warning.